# Issue with Async module on a remote server

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I get an issue on my remote server with the Async module used with ExpressJS, it works in local but not on my remote server...

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
     at Object.parse (native)
     at /home/anthoc/apps/instaprint.fr/routes/index.js:62:20
     at fn (/home/anthoc/apps/instaprint.fr/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:582:34)
     at Object._onImmediate (/home/anthoc/apps/instaprint.fr/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:498:34)
     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

My code :

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        var postData = {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
            code: CODE
        }
        var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
        request.post({
            uri: url,
            form: postData
        }, function (err, res, body) {
            callback(null,body);
        });
    }, function (body, callback) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        TOKEN = data.access_token;
        USER_ID = data.user.id;
        callback(null);
    }], function (err, result) {
        res.redirect('/photos');
    }
);
```

**EDIT #1 :**

The result of the "console.log(body)" :

```
 <html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>
 An internal server error occured.
 </body></html>
```

**EDIT #2 :**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
  at Object.parse (native)
  at /home/anthoc/apps/instaprint.fr/routes/index.js:63:20
  at fn (/home/anthoc/apps/instaprint.fr/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:582:34)
  at Object._onImmediate (/home/anthoc/apps/instaprint.fr/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:498:34)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Code :

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        var postData = {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
            code: CODE
        }
        var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
        request.post({
            uri: url,
            form: postData
        }, function (err, res, body) {
            callback(null,body);
        });
    }, function (body, callback) {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
        req.accepts('application/json');
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        TOKEN = data.access_token;
        USER_ID = data.user.id;
        callback(null);
    }], function (err, result) {
        res.redirect('/photos');
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error has nothing to do with async, and everything to do with the body you're getting back from your POST not being valid JSON.  Throw a `console.log(body)` above the `JSON.parse(body)` and you'll see.

Comment: Try sending a `"Content-Type": "application/json"` and `"Accept": "application/json"` header with your request. This will tell the server you are requesting that you are sending a `json` body and want a `json` response. However, the 500 error indicates that something is wrong on instagram's side (Or they're really bad at sending helpful error messages).

Comment: Ok, so it's not an async problem.  Maybe change the title of your question to "problem connecting to Instagram API" to attract better help.  In the meantime, check that all of the data that you're `POST`ing to Instagram is correct...

Comment: Everything works in local... The issue is only on my remote server...

Comment: Same issue, see edit 2...